# Why does Ant recognize some env vars but not others

Tags: java, ant, environment-variables

I have 2 env vars defined:

```
myuser@mymachine:~$ echo $ANT_HOME
/home/myuser/apache/ant/1.8.4/apache-ant-1.8.4
myuser@mymachine:~$ echo $ANT_IVY_HOME
/home/myuser/apache/ivy/apache-ivy-2.3.0-rc2
```

I have the following Ant build:

```
<property environment="env"/>

<target name="testant">
    <echo message="Ant home: ${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
    <echo message="Ant ivy home: ${env.ANT_IVY_HOME}"/>
</target>
```

When I run `testant` I get the following console output:

```
Buildfile: /home/myuser/eclipse/workspace/myapp/build.xml
testant:
    [echo] Ant home: /home/myuser/apache/ant/1.8.4/apache-ant-1.8.4
    [echo] Ant ivy home: ${env.ANT_IVY_HOME}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 316 milliseconds
```

Why does Ant recognize `ANT_HOME` but not `ANT_IVY_HOME`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, ant does not filter anything like this. Are you doing the echo and calling ant in the same shell?

Answer (score 2):

Did you merely set `ANT_IVY_HOME` and not **export** it?

Comment: Thanks @smooth reggae (+1) - but no, `ANT_IVY_HOME` is defined/exported in `.bashrc`...